# Connect mongo db replica set from other server Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have load balance with three server and 1 is main server storing data into database from server 2 and 3 via tunnel ssh using mongoose, currently I have only one port let's say 1900 but I wanna increase replica member 3 or more, Anyone know how to do?

Sorry for English might not correct, Thank you

```
const config = {
 username: 'root',
 host: '128.199.xx.xx',
 port: 22,
 agent: 345,
 dstPort: 1900,
 password: 'xxx'
 };
 tunnel(config, function (error, server) {
    mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:1900/db_name", {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      replicaSet: "rs",
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("MongoDB Connected");
    })
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding hosts to origin machine Thank you very much.We dont need any ssh tunnel any more

**1. Allow your Local IP to your server**

```
ufw allow from xx.xx.xx.xx to any port xxxx (database port)
```

**Optional: Adding IP to host file in your local machine**

For better security please addming username and password to access Databse